# How to refresh cached images if the image is updated but the URL doesn't change

Tags: reactjs, react-native, amazon-s3, caching

I want to cache images using the [react-native-fast-image](https://github.com/DylanVann/react-native-fast-image) library. Image URLs will not be changed over time. But the images can be changed. So the Image change will not change the image on the app. Images are stored in S3. For a solution what I thought was to keep a last image updated timestamp on the Firebase side. So when I'm updating the images I can change the timestamp and place it at the end of the image URLs.

So the image URLs will look like this

```
http://localhost/chair.jpg?${last_updated_timestamp}
http://localhost/chair.jpg?${last_updated_timestamp}
```

I'm thinking of saving the `last_updated_timestamp` in Async Storage, So I can sync the timestamp from Firebase to Async Storage and use it directly for the images.

Is there any other better way I can achieve the same result?

Comment: No, what you're doing works. Convention is to actually assign it to a param (e.g: `t` or `v` => `http://localhost/chair.jpg?t=${new Date().valueOf()}`. But there's a major downside to it: you're disabling caching for all images in your app across every new publish. Every time you publish, every client will have to re-download all images, even if they haven't changed.

Comment: @tao is there any better way to handle this scenario? I'm very thankful if you can guide me

Comment: I'd use the filesize, if its avaiable.

Answer (score 1):

This library provides a different types of caching control.

```
source.cache?: enum
FastImage.cacheControl.immutable - (Default) - Only updates if url changes.
FastImage.cacheControl.web - Use headers and follow normal caching procedures.
FastImage.cacheControl.cacheOnly - Only show images from cache, do not make any network requests.
```

[react-native-fast-image](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-fast-image)

In your cache url will not change so you can use simple caching for that component as below

```
 <FastImage
    source={{
      uri: item.image_url,
      headers: { Accept: "*/*" },
      priority: FastImage.priority.high,
      cache: FastImage.cacheControl.web
    }}/>
```

Comment: Thanks. But this will not change the image in the app If I replace the image on the s3 with the same URL

Answer (score 0):

Do u know frequency of updating your imag it can be used.

Set MAX-AGE of caching on image this value can be how often that image can be updated even if you will not changed it this image will be pulled again after MAX-AGE so be sure of what value be used

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

S3 has cache too. Our production project use S3. We have same problems with cache. And we use query params.

Its simply and effective solution if you have to solve problem at frontend.

Other solution will be related to configure not only react-native-fast-image but S3 too. Our devops didnt think that its his problem and we use query params)))

Answer (score 0):

it has also happened to me a couple of months ago. I have image URL like this

`https://myown.server/images/1122.png` . Image on the server was change but it does not  change on the application. I have find a simple solution for this as this.

```
<Image src={{uri:`${imge_url?new Date()}`}} />
```

Hope this will solve your problem .

Comment: From this solution, the image will load each and every time. So no use in cache

Answer (score -1):

you can try like this  key=${this.state.source.uri}${new Date()}